# Why can I connect to my hosted website database using localhost?

Tags: php, mysql

This might be a stupid question but why am i using local host if my site is being hosted with rackspace?

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "*****";
$db_pass = "********";
$db_name = "lds";


$link = mysql_connect('localhost','*****','*********');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
```

It appears to be getting a connection because I'm successfully echoing 'Connected successfully'.

Maybe something is terribly wrong because i noticed when i took out localhost from both mysql_connect function and from the db_host variable... it still says connected successfully.

Would that be because i've already wired the ftp connections up in my IDE?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP (and your database) runs on the remote server, so it is `localhost` from your host's (Rackspace) perspective.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks all for the help.. one more quick question... So If i decide to use mysqli or pdo do I have to reset-up my mysql db table to some different specifications?

Comment: @cookinggood If you want to get on track easy, change `mysql_` to `mysqli_`, but if you want to start with good coding habbits, create a link to `mysqli` or `PDO` with a class: `$db = new mysqli();` and make queries like `$db->connect()` (whichever the system you use, use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database server is running locally to the remote machine, where you are executing your PHP script(s). To your script the database appears to be `localhost` even though the web server and database server are remote relative to you.

Per the documentation for [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/function.mysql-connect):

> If the PHP directive mysql.default_host is undefined (default), then
>   the default value is 'localhost:3306'.

This would seem to indicate that if no value for the database server is provided, the default is used. Also note that the documentation also states that this function is **deprecated** in PHP 5.5.0.

See instead: http://php.net/mysqli and http://php.net/pdo

Comment: Thanks, so If i decide to use mysqli or pdo do I have to reset-up my mysql db table to some different specifications?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your php we server and the MySQL database server are on the same machine localhost will work